rescue-usage within Rails-action without begin
How does this work without the begin-keyword?
def show
  @post = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_path
end

Why isn't it?
def show
  begin
    @post = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

Both variations work. I've tried it. But I struggle understanding the first one.

"If you are inside a method, you do not need to use begin or end unless you wish to limit the scope of rescued exceptions:"

Thanks a lot. If you like turn your comment to answer. I will accept it.

begin/end is just one of the places where rescue can be used. Just replace begin with def or do and it is conceptually the same:
begin
  err
rescue
  "error"
end

def m
  err
rescue
  "error"
end

[1].map do |i|
  err
rescue
  "error"
end

class and module also work, not sure what you would use it for:
class A
  err
rescue
  "error"
end

module B
  err
rescue
  "error"
end

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html
